# When is Jquery pseudo recussion finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursive-query

I use the function below to show a list of items. I want to change the function so that I can display the navigation when the pseudo recussion is finished. Is there a way to dtect when it is finished?

```
function fadeItem() {
    $('ul li:hidden:first').fadeIn(fadeItem);
}
```

Comment: So do you want one by one to fade in and not all at once?

Comment: I want the list items to fade in one by one (FadeItem function), but when All items have faded in I want to display a div with navigation items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(update: added this first part) *Loads all embed images* then recursively fades everything in every half second, then does an alert (replace with the  concept you commented back on)

```
var selector = "ul li:hidden:first";
function fadeIn($item) {
   $item.fadeIn(500,function() {
      var n = $(selector);
      if(n.length > 0) {
         fadeIn($(selector));
      } else {
         // add a div
         alert("added a div");
      }

   })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   // load images first
   var imgs = []; // cached
   $("ul li img").each(function() {
      // create a separate img tag because img is not active due do [assumed css] display:none;
      var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
      cacheImage.src = $(this).attr("src");
      imgs.push(cacheImage);
   });
   // this is a quick method, you can change window to the image nodes to optimize better
   $(window).load(function() {
      fadeIn($(selector));
   });
});
```

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/MattLo/ukLaG/1/  (using a very large image to test)

Comment: Each li contains an img (external). Is there a way to only display the li if the image has a width or does not provide on error?

Comment: I updated the post, this will load all the images in (based on <img> tags) THEN fade everything in THEN do your final <div> action. The demo link is also updated

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/). You can pass a callback function:

```
function fadeItem() {
     $('ul li:hidden:first').fadeIn(fadeItem, function() {
         // do something
     });
}
```